# Error : The entity passed to the choice field must be managed

Tags: symfony

In a search form, when I submit for the second time the datas containing a equipment criterion, I receive this error :

> Entity of type "App\Entity\Equipment" passed to the choice field must be
>   managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

There is a example flow to reproduce the problem :

1. I introduce criteria (without equipment criterion) to find the corresponding adverts
2. I submit the serach form
3. The adverts are showed without problem
4. I introduce one or many equipment criteria (via a multiple choices list of entity type)
5. I submit the serach form
6. The adverts are showed without problem
7. I introduce for the second time one or many new equipment criteria
8. I submit the search form
9. I receive the error :

> Entity of type "App\Entity\Equipment" passed to the choice field must be
>   managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

Somebody have an idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: <<Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?>> i think the error is clear. did you checked if you are persisting corectly your entites?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I don't have to persist anything because it isn't a storing form but a form to do a search. However, I'm maybe wrong.

Comment: Maybe you are clearing the entity manager in between the submissions and thus your choices are no longer treated as persisted by the entity manager.

Comment: I don't know how the entity manager can be deleted. So, I don't know where to look.